# Is there router-view in nativescript vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-vue

Writing nativescript vuejs I have the following structure:

```
-src/
-- App.vue
-- views/
--   Login.vue
```

In vuejs we utilize `<router-view>` in App.vue and use routing to render Login.vue. How do I need proceed using nativescript?